# How to change file creation time under Mac OS X 10.3 Panther?

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, xcode, filesystem

According to this page https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/99599/430607 creation time can be changed with Xcode Command Line Tools.

```
SetFile -d
```

But where can I get Xcode Command Line Tools for Mac OS X 10.3?

Is there perhaps another solution? I want to set my timestamps for my files correctly.

[image]

Comment: What about touch?

Comment: For 10.3 I think the tools came on the OSX CDs

Comment: @SolarMike I think touch only does modification and access times as defined by POSIX. Creation time is HFS only

Comment: I think OSX 10.3 needs Xcode tools 1.5 and the CD is still on the Apple Developer site see bottom of https://developer.apple.com/download/all/?q=xcode

Comment: Perhaps this technique https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/40979/9388 could be modified?

Comment: @mmmmmm Thanks it worked with Xcode 1.5. I have updated the main post and show a tutorial how it works.

Comment: @swr3gjt You should convert that solution into an answer, and then (after the mandatory delay) mark that as the accepted solution (unless someone else gives an even better answer, in which case accept that instesad). See [this FAQ](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 1):

For early versions of Mac OS X, Xcode and its command line tools came on a CD/DVD with the operating system. So the original disks should be the main source.

Apple also provides downloads of most versions of Xcode in the developer support [site](https://developer.apple.com/download/all/?q=xcode). You need an Apple Developer login for that but the free version works for this.

For Mac OS X 10.3 you need Xcode Tools 1.5

Answer (score 1):

---

### **Update**

After installing Xcode 1.5, `SetFile` is in this directory.

`/Developer/Tools/SetFile`

A link should be made for the default bin directory.

```
sudo ln -s /Developer/Tools/SetFile /usr/bin/SetFile
```

[image]

---

### **Update 2**

Now change the file creation time with `SetFile`.

```
SetFile -d "07/06/2005 02:00:00" /Users/unnunn/Documents/Untitled.rtf
```

[image]

Comment: Might be better to link it into /usr/local/bin so it won‘t get overwritten by an update.