# How can I modify the "Date Added" of a file via the terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, filesystem

Whenever I move files between folders or to an external hard drive, I lose the "Date Added" metadata of the files. I need this info for sorting purposes. How can I change that field via the command line?

It's multiple files, and I need the date added to be the same the as date created for each file. So I assume I need a short script? Googling only leads me to "Date Modified" and "Date Created" but I need "Date Added". I am on the latest macOS update.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/40941/how-to-set-date-added-metadata-in-mac-os-x-10-7-lion

Comment: I wish people would understand that "date added" is not metadata specific to a file. It is metadata relating a file and a folder.